Pair to Mac in Visual Studio 2022 Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
I have the latest version of visual studio 2022 (17.11.3 and before  I had an older version 17.9.6, but it didn't work either) and today I have updated the XCode to the latest (16.0) version for iOS 18.0.
But when it finishes installing when trying to pair with the mac I get the following error: Object reference not set as an instance of an object.
I have tried to delete both the XMA folder from the mac and my PC (Windows), but it still does not work for me.
I even get the same error when I use another pc to connect to the mac.
Restarting Visual Studio, My computer or my Mac does not help.
Now I can't connect to my Mac does someone else have it?

I just experienced this as well, as i'm migrating from xamarin to MAUI. I utilized the hack others mentioned by adding DisableMonoValidation to my windows machine's Registry Editor https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-Pair-to-mac-gives-Object-reference-no/10670625#T-N10671407
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/22722

It appears that winehq took over hosting the Mono-Project today. It's just a wild guess, but it could have something to do with that change: https://www.winehq.org/news/2024091701

Here is a screenshot of the "hack" I mentioned in the comment. It was mentioned in GitHub/Microsoft developer threads that a fix was previously released. Unsure whether it was reintroduced again. But one should remove this from the Registry, once the error is resolved.


It works , but we are waiting for soloution by microsoft

@B.Geronatsios Yes, because it's a bit of a weird solution to skip validation

Now I have a problem that it can't find iOS simulators because the mac version (16.0) is not compatible with the version of my visual Studio which is the latest...

@Giorgio I got the same issue. The registry hack gets me connected to the Mac, but still can't use the simulator. It says "No simulators (Xcode mismatch)".
Visual Studio 17.11.3, MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1 and Xcode 16.0.

Thanks for finally mentioning how to add the Registry item

@RickardN I post a question

This is a temporary solution. The problem is actually caused by the service located at https://software.xamarin.com/service/products returning with a 403 error code. You can undo the change in the registry when this service is opened. Feedback has been forwarded to the Microsoft team, details are at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pair-to-mac-Mono-Validation-is-not-worki/10746931

It was broken with 403 yesterday.  It's 503 today.  Please upvote the following as it's insane that Microsoft can't fix this without editing the registry.  Surely, VS can ignore the error if valid tools are installed on the Mac.  And why are we dependant on a single App Service that no one keeps an eye on?
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Pair-to-Mac-should-not-fail-if-the-Xamar/10746659
Unfortunately, the registry hack (disabling Mono tooling check) doesn't help if you don't already have compatible tooling installed on the Mac.

In the end I downgraded Xcode to 15.4 and it worked.

This could be a comment.
